# Failed to allocate using bitmap - Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, allocation

I tried to apply few images on the UI .And I used `bitmap` to achieve this because I don't have any space to use a simple `setImageResource` .
The problem says Failed to allocate.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 93600012 byte allocation with 16765312 free bytes and 70MB until OOM

I would be happy if you can help me to solve this problem.

```
int imgResource = item.getIcon(); // for example imgResource = R.drawable.test
Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(imgResource); //Here I get the error 
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();
holder.iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Thanks !

Comment: How big is the image? (width x height)

Comment: this will help u https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html

Comment: @SteveSmith This code is a part of function, the function get 25 images and every image is different.

Comment: Does it need to show all 25 images at the same time?  If not, you probably need to recycle them when they're finished with.

Comment: I guess you are trying to load the images in a list then why don't you try [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) .

Comment: @SteveSmith Yes, it should show all the images, In general the application show the user a list of channels images.

Comment: if you are using local image try to compress and also opt for Local cache, this link contain all info https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: @android_hub The Picasso make differs but it is still not the answer for the problem, Almost there ...

Comment: @Pavan I already try to use Bitmap but without any success, Maybe do you have another example to achieve the mission with the Bitmap and Memory Cache ? Thanks for all !

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. Add `android:largeHeap="true"`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

use this method and pass context and image file name:

```
public Bitmap getAssetImage(Context context, String filename) throws IOException {
    AssetManager assets = context.getResources().getAssets();
    InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream((assets.open("drawable/" + filename + ".png")));
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buffer);
    return bitmap;
   // return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);
}
```

Comment: I try that, Bat this is not the "best" answer to handle with this problem because It is still full up all the memory.

Comment: I try that But now all the images are white. Do you know why ?